# Impedir eliminar mas de un registro a la vez con un trigger en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Necesito implementar algo similar a lo que hace  SQLServer pero en Oracle:

CODIGO: SQLSERVER

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_ImpideBorradoMultiple 
   ON MiTabla AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
   IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Deleted) > 1
   Begin
      raiserror('Prohibido eliminar mas de un registro a la vez', 16, 1)
      rollback transaction
   End
END
```

Por lo que he visto, en Oracle existen las variables :Old y :New, que son de tipo %rowtype por tanto solo referencian a la fila afectada, en cambio en SQLServer, Deleted hace referencia al conjunto de filas afectadas... Debo concluir entonces que no se puede hacer esto en Oracle???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de revisar la documentación de Oracle, efectivamente solo se puede acceder al registro afectado y nunca al conjunto de ellos. Por lo tanto, se me ocurre la siguiente solución: Utilizar una tabla (puede ser temporal) que contabilice las eliminaciones en un trigger para cada fila de tipo before (antes de); luego con un trigger de orden de tipo after (después de), consultar por lo contabilizado:

```
Create or Replace Trigger Tr_CalculaEliminacionMultiple
   Before delete
   On Empleados
   for each row  /*este trigger se ejecuta por cada fila afectada*/
Begin
   Update EmpleCuentaDeleteRows /*tabla para contabilizar filas afectadas*/
   Set NumFilas = NumFilas + 1;
end;


/*Trigger se dispara despues de la ejecución de la orden.*/
Create or Replace Trigger Tr_EvitaEliminacionMultiple
   after delete
   On Empleados
Declare
   Filas number;
Begin

   Select NumFilas into Filas
   from EmpleCuentaDeleteRows; /*tabla para contabilizar filas afectadas.*/

   if Filas > 1 Then
      raise_application_error(-20001,'No se puede!!!');
   else
      update EmpleCuentaDeleteRows
      set NumFilas = 0;
   end if;
end;
```

Creo que el rendimiento se verá afectado, en comparación con SQL-SERVER, pero no veo otra alternativa.

Answer (score 0):

La [documentación de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_tr.htm) es bastante concisa al respecto:

> Because the trigger uses the FOR EACH ROW clause, it might be executed
>   multiple times, such as when updating or deleting multiple rows. You
>   might omit this clause if you just want to record the fact that the
>   operation occurred, but not examine the data for each row.

Si el trigger usa el `FOR EACH ROW` se ejecutará por cada fila, se puede omitir esta cláusula, por ejemplo para registrar que ocurrió un `DELETE` pero no vas a poder examinar los datos involucrados, por consiguiente no vas a poder determinar si se trata de un `delete` de múltiples registros como para disparar un error e impedir la operación.

Answer (score -1):

Como mencionas Oracle tiene los objetos :new y :old, estos solo afectan al registro que se esta modificando, podrías describir mejor lo que quieres hacer y cual es el problema. Si adjuntas el código sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: Lo que busco es implementar un requerimiento: impedir que se eliminen de forma masiva registros de una tabla, es decir, evitar: DELETE FROM DETALLECOMPRAS, sin ninguna restricción where.

Comment: Esto es un comentario, no una respuesta